# flood fill algorithm crashing in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to fill color in a polygon using the flood fill recursive algorithm. I am coding in python 2.7. I goes halfway towards the filling then crashes. It happens all the time I run the code. Is there any thing wrong with the code or it's just the problem in my laptop. Please help? Thank you. Here is the code.

```
    import pygame
    import numpy as np
    from pygame.locals import *
    import sys
    def flood_fill(name, x, y, color):
        get = name.get_at((x, y))
        if get == (0, 0, 0, 255):
            screen.set_at((x, y), red)
            pygame.display.flip()
            flood_fill(name, x + 1, y, color)
            flood_fill(name, x - 1, y, color)
            flood_fill(name, x, y + 1, color)
            flood_fill(name, x, y - 1, color)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
        pygame.init()
        sys.setrecursionlimit(1500000000)
        width = 640
        height = 480
        resolution = (width, height)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
        black = (0, 0, 0)
        white = (255, 255, 255)
        red = (255, 0, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [20, 20, 250, 100], 2)
        flood_fill(screen, 100, 50, red)
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What is the error message on crashing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pygame`, but I guess that you have illegal indices in `name.get_at((x, y))`. Check the coordinates or catch the exception in question with `pass` (which probably isn't good style).

Comment: @MOehm I thought the same but i think his function should not ever get to illegal parameters because his passed parameters ensure the floodfill would terminate before the edges of screen(if written correctly off course). Think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @VikramBhat: Okay, there's a white rectangle bounding the starting point. I have to admit that I didn't pay too much attention to the client code.

Comment: @user1915729 Why you using (0,0,0,255) for comparison whereas you need only three tuples to compare (r,g,b) ?

Comment: this is what the crash report shows:Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 527fcf56
  Fault Module Name: python27.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.7.6150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp: 527fcf52
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 000fce63
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 9b43
  Additional Information 2: 9b431b0c90e83ec68d3d9c2ff7e024e8
  Additional Information 3: feb7
  Additional Information 4: feb7fc1b4ccfe33f19ad35c220a990e4

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your recursion limit is the problem. All setrecursionlimit does really is remove the warnings that would prevent you from doing stupid things; it does not magically create the transistors in your CPU to hold a 1500000000 call stack.

Implementing a floodfill on the stack is generally speaking a bad idea. Use a stack datastructure in a while loop instead.

Comment: But for following case his max stack space needed is 250*100 which will is less than 1MB space should not be problem for stackoverflow ?

Comment: Not sure how you get at that number; does his cpu only have 40 bytes worth of registers? I doubt it, but if so hed be working on some kind of embedded CPU with only a few kb of memory or so. That's not even counting local variables. The python docs note that setrecursionlimit may lead to crashes; and its the only unsafe thing he is doing. Regardless, there is no reason to be using all that memory for a simple floodfill, and especially not your limited stack memory.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorm I am only saying that inbuilt stack based floodfill is not that bad as compared to stack data structure based in terms of space complexity though might be slower. yes maybe there is no need for setrecursionlimit

Comment: when I remove the recursion limit python throws me an error saying recursion depth limited. Also, is there any alternative the flood fill color algorithm?

Comment: Throwing an error is a step up from a crash ;). The simplest alternative is to store the information you want to stack in RAM, rather than in your CPU callstack. Since you wont be storing all your registers and other useless info, youd be using much less memory, of a kind which you also have orders of magnitude more of. Simply write a while loop, append candidate pixels to a list, and pop off a new pixel off the list at the start of the loop, until your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the error that you are getting, but based on the code, I think that the error is the `IndexError`  and you should check if pixel coordinates are valid coordinates i.e. they always are inside the area of the surface which is in your case the `screen`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at): `If the pixel position is outside the area of the Surface an IndexError exception will be raised.`

Just make sure, that `get_at` method gets valid parameters or surround it with the `try\except` block.

Comment: thought the same but reconsidered it because parameters he passed to floodfill seem to avoid the case that values reach the edges of screen.

Comment: @VikramBhat I'm pretty sure that invalid calls are generated by recursive calls. For example, he calls `flood_fill(name, x - 1, y, color)` without checking if `x-1` is valid.

Comment: I am sure that would happen in general case but the parameters he has passed to function is trying to paint a rectangle by applying floodfill on point inside rectangle so it will be terminated at boundaries in any case without reaching invalid co-ordinates. Therefore i dont think that is the only problem